# Get distinct record with multiple like

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select Distinct 
p.ProductID,
p.SingleAppPrice,
p.ImageURL,
p.IconURL,
p.ProductName,
p.ActPrice,
c.CategoryIcon,
c.CategoryName,
s.SubCategoryName,
p.Rating,
p.AuthorID 
from 
ProductMast p,CategoryMast c,SubCategoryMast s 
where 
c.CategoryID=p.CategoryID 
and s.SubCategoryID=p.SubCategoryID 
and p.Keywords like '%application%' 
or p.ProductName like '%application%' 
or c.CategoryName like '%application%' 
or s.SubCategoryName like '%application%'
```

When i am fire this query i got 121 record because of multiple use of like, how to prevent this repeation. Total record is 11

Comment: Without any type of sample data this question is meaningless. We can't guess what you have or what you need.

Comment: _"When i am fire this query i got 121 record because of multiple use of like, how to prevent this repeation. Total record is 11"_ `WHERE` filters records, so it cannot cause more records. But `from ProductMast p,CategoryMast c,SubCategoryMast s` creates a carthesian product. Use a `Join`.

Comment: @lc i am trying to search application with different column using like but when application is contains in more than one column repeation is start

Comment: You mean you have 11 products ? By the way, the or clauses without parenthesis may often give you undesired results... if you're not really aware of precedence order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an precedence order problem with your AND and OR clauses.

There may be also something wrong in your table join, but I can't answer about this

here

```
c.CategoryID=p.CategoryID 
and s.SubCategoryID=p.SubCategoryID
```

Anyway.

the minimal correction would be

```
select Distinct 
 p.ProductID,
 p.SingleAppPrice,
 p.ImageURL,
 p.IconURL,
 p.ProductName,
 p.ActPrice,
 c.CategoryIcon,
 c.CategoryName,
 s.SubCategoryName,
 p.Rating,
 p.AuthorID 
from 
 ProductMast p,CategoryMast c,SubCategoryMast s 
where 
 c.CategoryID=p.CategoryID 
 and s.SubCategoryID=p.SubCategoryID 
 and (p.Keywords like '%application%' 
      or p.ProductName like '%application%' 
      or c.CategoryName like '%application%' 
      or s.SubCategoryName like '%application%')
```

Now, of course, the good syntax with join clauses would be

```
select Distinct 
   p.ProductID,
   p.SingleAppPrice,
   p.ImageURL,
   p.IconURL,
   p.ProductName,
   p.ActPrice,
   c.CategoryIcon,
   c.CategoryName,
   s.SubCategoryName,
   p.Rating,
   p.AuthorID 
from 
 ProductMast p,
 join CategoryMast c on c.CategoryID = p.CategoryId 
 join SubCategoryMast s on s.SubCategoryID = p.SubCategoryID
where 
 (p.Keywords like '%application%' 
 or p.ProductName like '%application%' 
 or c.CategoryName like '%application%' 
 or s.SubCategoryName like '%application%')
```

Comment: @HughJones you mean concatenation ? It's `+` in Sql Server, `||` is for Oracle, then...

Comment: @HughJones By the way, you may have side effects if any of the search field is nullable... and null (should use some Coalesce operators to avoid this).

Comment: I thought about that - I think your version is the same though, so still 'equivalent'

Comment: @HughJones no, it's not equivalent. The whole concatenated value will be null if one of its element is null.

Comment: As would your entire `OR` statement

Comment: select Distinct 
   p.ProductID,
   p.SingleAppPrice,
   p.ImageURL,
   p.IconURL,
   p.ProductName,
   p.ActPrice,
   c.CategoryIcon,
   c.CategoryName,
   s.SubCategoryName,
   p.Rating,
   p.AuthorID 
from 
 ProductMast p,CategoryMast c,SubCategoryMast s
 where 
 c.CategoryID = p.CategoryId 
 s.SubCategoryID = p.SubCategoryID
 and 
 (p.Keywords like '%application%' 
 or p.ProductName like '%application%' 
 or c.CategoryName like '%application%' 
 or s.SubCategoryName like '%application%')            What is diffetence in your query and this query? Any performance difference?

Comment: @HughJones Yup. Still surprised by (strange) differences in db implmentations ;) ? You can also mix types in concatenation in Oracle, while you have to cast all to varchar in Sql Server, etc., etc. !

Comment: Not just that, but the fiddle shows the OPPOSITE behaviour from what I expected - yes they are equivalent, but both forms return 3 rows.  I resign. :)

Comment: @PareshGami Performance is probably the same (hoping the db engine is smart enough), but the join query is really better (easier to read, the relationship part is clearer, and separated from the real "WHERE" filters). Also, LEFT JOIN can't be done with your syntax, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your `from` clause causes a cartesian product between three tables. So all records of all tables are combined with each other. That's what causes more records than the total-count.

Instead `join` these columns on foreign-keys to the parent table's primary key.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.productid, 
                p.singleappprice, 
                p.imageurl, 
                p.iconurl, 
                p.productname, 
                p.actprice, 
                c.categoryicon, 
                c.categoryname, 
                s.subcategoryname, 
                p.rating, 
                p.authorid 
FROM   Productmast p 
       INNER JOIN Categorymast c 
               ON p.categoryid = c.categoryid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Subcategorymast s 
                    ON p.subcategoryid = s.subcategoryid 
WHERE  p.productname LIKE '%application%' 
        OR c.categoryname LIKE '%application%' 
        OR s.subcategoryname LIKE '%application%'
```

I'm not sure if you need `Distict` at all. I guess it is redundant.

Comment: I admit that the syntax is bad. But the real problem (even if I would also go with join syntax), is the missing parenthesis. Because the `c.CategoryID=p.CategoryID 
and s.SubCategoryID=p.SubCategoryID` do "the same" (in a bad way) as the join. But as the OR clauses are not between parenthesis, that's breaking the logic.

Comment: When i am trying snack to search again record is repeated. Display 6 record

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Code

```
WITH TempUsers (FirstName,LastName, duplicateRecordCount)
AS
(
SELECT FirstName,LastName,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITIONBY FirstName, LastName ORDERBY FirstName) AS duplicateRecordCount
FROM dbo.Users
)
DELETE
FROM TempUsers
WHERE duplicateRecordCount > 1
GO
```

Comment: I think it would be more heelpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: @reporter- Thank you for your advice..I will be careful next time